# Dictionary structure in firebase

Tags: firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database, data-structures

I want to write a program using a google Realtime DB firebase, The idea is similar to a dictionary, where one word is connected to many other words, and if you search for any of these words it will display all connected words.

I need to know how I can structure my data so I can implement my Idea, To be honest as starting I have no Idea where to start, Any idea, Links can help to start?

```
                  **------ UPDATE FIRST IDEA ---**
```

I am thinking to make a root for each word, and when searching for a word I can find all alternative/Synonyms words that connected to the root. Example:

Assume the root word is **FIND** with ID 1

and there is 3 alternative/Synonyms word **SEEK**,**SPOT**,**SEARCH**

The Data base will like

```
ID    word      rootID    
1     FIND       0    -- 0 means its a root word
2     SEEK       1    -- root word is FIND
3     SEARCH     1
4     SPOT       1
```

Now if I am searching for **SPOT**, then I know that **FIND** is the root, now I can find all words that has root ID 1 and Synonyms to word **FIND**

Comment: Try a minimum and show us the result.

Comment: What you mean try minimum ?

Comment: A minimal idea of yours. And if it doesn't work the way expect, edit your question and tell us why.